# Godot: Node not found

Tags: godot

Hi I'm currently making a game that houses minigames with Godot. After I finish the first minigame, that minigame can only be run when I play that specific scene.

When I try to run my whole project(starting from the main menu screen), it throws me an error(Attempt to call function 'get_node' in base 'null instance' on a null instance) saying my minigame node was not found. So I press the 'remote' button next to 'local' and see that my minigame scenetree is not there and that's why it cant detect the node.

I have tried adding the minigame scene as an autoload. This made it work and I can run it from the main menu again but then the things inside my minigame wont load so it became a blank screen when it arrives to the minigame scene.

How do I make it so my minigame will load properly and the project can be started from the main menu scene?

Answer (score 1):

---

### New Answer

So your code in Autoload is trying to access something that is not in Autoload.

As I said in the old answer, There is no guarantee that what the Autoload is trying to access is there. You cannot rely on it being loaded and available to the Autoload.

Of course, if you run the game form a scene, you could trust that particular scene is loaded. But if you start the at another scene, then that isn't the case. So what do you do in that case?

Well, you need to load the scene you need by whatever means (see old answer for ways to load a scene). And you need to pass the instance to Autoload.

One way to pass that instance, is to have a function in the code in Autoload that takes the Node as parameter. Then after you load the scene, you can call that function passing the instance.

To reiterate, your main scene will load the minigame scene (by whatever means), so it have an instance of it. Then it will get the Autoload, and call a function on it passing the instance.

---

Let us try again, in your main scene, you will load the minigame. That can be accomplished by different ways. For example, calling [`load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#instancing-scenes) with the resource path will give you a [`PackedScene`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html). Then you call [`instance`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html#class-packedscene-method-instance) on the `PackedScene` which gives you an instance.

Afterwards, you can add that instance to the scene tree using [`add_child`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child)...

That same instance you will pass it to the Autoload. The code in the Autoload needs a variable to store it, which you will set.

In your main scene you can use `get_node` to get the Autoload (and yes, an Autoload can be a scene). See [Singletons (AutoLoad)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html). And then set the variable with instance you loaded.

---

For completeness sake, I'll also mention that you can change scenes with [`change_scene`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-method-change-scene). The code in Autoload would remain when you do that. And this could make changing scenes simpler. However, if you later need to make something that was a separate scene a part of a bigger one, or if you decide that you need background loading, then having relied on `change_scene` will be an obstacle. See also [SceneTree](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scene_tree.html) and [Change scenes manually](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/change_scenes_manually.html).

---

### Old answer

First some organization. Where are you using `get_node`?

If you are using `get_node` in the the main scene to access the minigame. That is ok, you just need to make sure that the minigame is already loaded and in the node path you need it.

---

Remember that to use `get_node` you need a Node to begin with. Thus, either the code where you call `get_node` is a in a `Node`, or some other code gave a `Node` (e.g. as a parameter on a function call) to it. Also, what you are trying to get must be there.

These are the problematic cases:

- The code in the minigame is trying to access something else in the minigame. For this use **relative paths**, so that they work regardless of where the minigame is loaded. *Similarly, if the main scene is accessing something else form the main scene, that is ok.*
- The code in the minigame is trying to access something in another scene (e.g. the main menu). Avoid doing this. Use signals for this kind of cummincation instead. *Accessing the Autoload in the minigame is ok.*
- The code in an Autoload is an scene (yes, you can put a scene in Autoload) trying to access something that is NOT in Autoload. Avoid doing this. There is no guarantee that what the Autoload is trying to access is there.
- The code in an Autoload is using `get_node` on a node some other code gave to it. You probably can have that other code give the node the Autoload needs directly.

See [Node communication](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/basics/node_communication/) and [Understanding Node Paths](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/basics/getting_nodes/).

---

Second, there are other things that you could be presuming to be true in your code, that might not be once it is loaded somewhere else. Such as:

- What camera is the current camera. *You may have to change cameras when you load the scene, or to consider the position of the current camera in your code.*
- That the position of the root of the scene is at the global origin. *You may need to distinguish global and local position, or set the position of the scene when you load it.*

---

And third, there are many ways to load a scene, for starters:

- You can, of course, simply add the scene to the scene tree. This is the simplest way to do it (I remind you that you can set visibility). *This adds to the load time of the scene.* Always start with this option, and only move to something else if it gives you problems.
- You can also put it on Autoload. Autoload is good for things that should be accesible no matter when or where. I doubt that is the case of the minigame. *This adds to the load time of the game.*

These methods have one important drawback: the minigame is loaded preemptively. Which may make loading the game slower. If load time is a problem, you might prefer to load it on demand. For that we have more options:

- You can get a [`PackedScene`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html) of your minigame in code using [`load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#instancing-scenes) (passing the resource path as parameter) and then [`instance`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html#class-packedscene-method-instance), and [`add_child`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child).
- You [`preload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-preload) (passing the resource path as parameter) to get the `PackedScene`. And then when you need it, you can `instance` and `add_child`.
- You could instead use `class_name` (see [Register scripts as classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#register-scripts-as-classes)) which would let you instance it with `new`. If it is a node, you can add it to scene tree with `add_child` afterwards. It might not be a node, which is also useful sometimes. By the way, you can give it static functions, which you could call without instantiating it (no static variables, if you want static variables use Autoload instead).
- You can put the scene on the scene tree, as a place holder. On the Scene panel (on the left of the editor by default), open the contextual menu (right click) on the scene node, and select "Load as Placeholder". This results in a [`InstancePlaceholder`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_instanceplaceholder.html) node. You can call [`replace_by_instance`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_instanceplaceholder.html#class-instanceplaceholder-method-replace-by-instance) on it when you need it.

Drawback? When loading on demand, the game will halt while loading. If the individual things you are loading on demand are small enough, that is no problem. However for a large scene, it might be. That leads us to a final option:

- Use [background loading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.html). To do this, you use [`ResourceLoader.load_interactive`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceloader.html#class-resourceloader-method-load-interactive) passing the resource path as parameter. This gives you a [`ResourceInteractiveLoader`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceinteractiveloader.html), on which you can call `poll` to load the scene steadily. Once it is loaded you call [`get_resource`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceinteractiveloader.html#class-resourceinteractiveloader-method-get-resource), which gives you the `PackedScene` that you can `instance` and `add_child`.

Drawback? It is significantly more code in comparison with the other approaches. Ideally you would reuse it. In fact, you can put this logic on a Autoload, and that way it is available anywhere you need to load something.

*You could, in fact, use background loading to load the main menu. Then the main menu can load all it needs to work simply having it there in the scene tree. Which would also mean that the main menu is not the starting scene. Instead the starting scene uses background loading to load the main menu. Visually it could have a logo and a progress bar, or something along those lines. However, this suggestion is not for every game, only for those that take considerable time to load.*

---

In case of confusion: Node paths are in the scene tree, see [`get_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node) and [`NodePath`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html). And resource paths are in the project internal file system (the ones that start with `res://`), see [Data paths](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html).

Comment: I have a minigame scene called calibration1.tscn. In this scene, I have a control node as a parent and 3 other nodes, one of them is a grid container which I'm trying to call. I am using getnode on a script called Calibration1Manager.gd which is a singleton(autoload). The way im using it is (Calibration1.get_node('GridContainer').add_child(deck[c]) ).

Comment: @newbie112 Don't get from a singleton (which will be available always) something that is not in a singleton (which may or may not be available), only other things that are singletons. And if you are getting something from a singleton, make the singleton a scene instead of a script. Edit: ok, what I said is not an absolute, for example if you are passing a `Node` and a `NodePath` to the singleton. However, I'm not convinced you should be using singleton at all here.

Comment: @newbie112 So from where did the singleton get `Calibration1`?

Comment: Im not getting from a singleton. I mean that line of code is inside the singleton named Calibration1Manager.gd. I'm trying to get the Grid Container node under my Calibration1.tscn scene to add a child.

Comment: @newbie112 I noticed the word "from" is problematic (it could mean the place `get_node` is used, or it could mean the place `get_node` is trying to access), and thus I have edited the answer to not use it. I was asking: how did the code in the singleton get `Calibration1`? Yes, you have a `Calibration1.tscn`. But, is that loaded? Does the singleton have a reference to it? Edit: you could have some code pass the nodes the Autoload needs by calling a function on it. Other than that, I'd avoid code in Autoload acceding things that are not in Autoload.

Comment: Apparently it will work when I run it from the Calibration1.tscn scene. But if run it from my main menu scene it will throw the error.

Comment: I think its not loaded if I run it from the Main Menu. So how do I actually load it without making my Calibration1.tscn an autoload? Because making it an autoload will cause it 
 to not function

Comment: @newbie112 If you run from Calibration1.tscn it makes sense that that scene is available.  And as you have noticed, you cannot rely on that. When you run from the main menu, you need to load Calibration1.tscn, by whatever means… Then the code you have in Autoload needs a reference. I'm not convinced that code you currently have in Autoload should be in Autoload. However, if for whatever reason it must be, have the code that load Calibration1.tscn pass a reference to the code in Autoload (e.g. in the main menu get the a reference to the Autoload, and call a function on it passing Calibration1).

Comment: I mean like this the problem , the singleton cant get Calibration1.tscn and therefore cannot get the node.

Comment: If it is not in autoload, where do you think the code should be at? Attached to the parent node of Calibration1.tscn?

Comment: @newbie112 On the scene that needs it, or the scene it interacts with. In this case, yes I think that is Calibration1.tscn, you would add a node to it and put what you have in Autoload there. It is when multiple scene needs it that we would consider other means (either make a named class or use Autoload).

Comment: Wait, what do you mean add a node? I have to add a new node to my Calibration1.tscn?

Comment: @newbie112 Assuming the node that is root on that scene already have code, and you don't want to mess with it, you can add another node child of it to add the code. It is not the only way to do that, that seems the less disruptive to me.

Comment: I think I really do need the Autoload cause there is another script that is dependent on it. Therefore, I will try to preload in from the Main Menu. Hope it works

Comment: By the way, do you know why if I just add my Calibration1.tscn as an autoload, it will not work?

Comment: @newbie112 All the Autoload are available all the time (unless you go out of your way to remove them), and it is OK for them to access each other directly. I would resist adding thing to Autoload. You can imagine a situation where you end up adding a lot of things to Autoload because other things in Autoload need them. It is better to put everything in the main scene instead.